# Solving a $4$th order initial value problem with three initial conditions and an asymptotic condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Obtain the solution for $$( D^4 + 6 D^3 + 9 D^2) y=0,$$ where $D = \frac{d}{dx}$, where $$x=0,  y=0,  y'=0,  y''= 6,$$
>   and as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, $y'$ tends to $1$.
>   For this particular solution, find the value of $y$ when $x =1$.

I solved this as follows:

The roots associated with the auxillary eqn of the given differential eqn are $m= 0,0,-3,-3$.
The general solution is
$$y(x) = a + b x+ c \exp(-3x) + d x \exp(-3x).$$
Then,
\begin{align}
y' (x) &= b - [3 c \exp (-3x) ]- [ 3 d x \exp(-3x)]+ d \exp(-3x) \\
y''(x) &= 9 c \exp(-3x)+ (9x-6) d \exp(-3x).
\end{align}
On substituting the initial conditions to above eqns I got
\begin{align}
a+c &=0\\
b-3c+d &=0\\
9c-6d &= 6 .
\end{align}
Now I am not getting how to solve these for the constants $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Use MathJax to write your equations .It will be more comprehensive and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean,

> *as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, $y'$ tends to $1$*,

and not *as $x$ tends to $0$*.

This gives, in addition to the three (linear) conditions you've already identified, a fourth constraint, that is,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} y'(x) = b = 1.$$
These four conditions together determine the unknown coefficients $a, b, c, d$.

Comment: Yes, I am extremly sorry for the mistake.

Comment: So is it second constant b=1?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this says.

Comment: Yes, I got the desired answer. Your idea helped me, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.